# shell read pass two variables in for or while loop and ssh in multiple hosts

Tags: shell, ssh

```
master1: /tmp> cat example.txt

server1 ls
server2 ls
server3 ls
```

Want to achieve below,

```
master1:/tmp> cat example.txt|while read a b
do
  ssh $a $b
done
```

Problem : its only getting output from server1 and exiting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it again with this as your input file:

```
server1 cat
server2 cat
server3 cat
```

You should see the following output:

```
server2 cat
server3 cat
```

Why? Because the first `ssh` command is capturing standard input and reading until EOF. When it's exhausted, the `read` loop closes as well.

A quick fix is to use the `-n` flag to tell `ssh` to use `/dev/null` for stdin internally.

```
while read host cmd; do
  ssh -n "$host" "$cmd"
done < file
```

(Aside: [Use quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting)!)